# Оптимизация spinner

Tags: java, android

Мой кастомный `Spinner` при первом клике на него долго открывается (~3 сек). Он состоит из 25 обьектов класса `Person`

```
public static class Person{
        private String name;
        private Drawable ic;

        Person(String name,Drawable ic){
            this.name=name;
            this.ic=ic;
        }

        public Drawable getIc() {
            return ic;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

При последующих кликах открывается примерно за ~1 сек.

Но в некоторых приложения я смотрю и вижу что кастомный `Spinner` имеет более 30 обьектов с `ImageView` и `TextView` и открывается моментально. Хотелось бы советов как достичь такого же результата.

Мой адаптер

```
private class AdapterSpinner extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
        private ArrayList<Person> objects;

        public AdapterSpinner(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Person> objects) {
            super(context, resource,objects);
            this.objects=new ArrayList<>();
            this.objects.addAll(objects);

        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getDropDownSpinnerView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getSpinnerView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getDropDownSpinnerView(int position, View convertView,
                                  ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.types_dropdown_spinner, parent, false);
            TextView text = row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(objects.get(position).getName());
            ImageView icon = row.findViewById(R.id.ic);
            icon.setImageDrawable(objects.get(position).getIc());
            return row;
        }

        public View getSpinnerView(int position, View convertView,
                                  ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.types_spinner, parent, false);
            ImageView icon =  row.findViewById(R.id.ic);
            icon.setImageDrawable(objects.get(position).getIc());
            return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте без icon.setImageDrawable , быстрее стало?

Comment: Для решения таких проблем есть Profiler, прогоните и узнаете где узкое место в производительности. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile

Comment: @Style-7 нет...